# Q: TypeError: '_csv.reader' object is not callable

Tags: python, typeerror, cs50

I keep getting this error, can anyone help me solve it? I have highlighted the problematic line of code below. I have tried to change the reader variable to reader1 but the problem persists.

**error message**

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "dna.py", line 20, in

reader = reader(peoplefile)

TypeError: '_csv.reader' object is not callable

**

- my code

**

```
from sys import argv

from csv import reader, DictReader



if len(argv) < 3:

print("Wrong number of arguments")

exit()



#read the database file into memory

with open(argv[2]) as file:

reader = reader(file)

for row in reader:

dnalist = row



#create a variable containing the sample DNA

dna = dnalist[0]

#create a dictionary that holds the STR and the highest rep count

sequences = {}



with open(argv[1]) as peoplefile:

reader = reader(peoplefile) **<------ ERROR IS HERE**

for row in reader:

dnasequences = row

dnasequences.pop(0)

break

#set the STRs as keys in sequences dictionary

for i in dnasequences:

sequences[i] = 1



#Obtain the highest number of reps of each STR in the given DNA sequence

for key in sequences:

l = len(i)

tmp = 0

tmpmax = 0

#check

for i in dna:

if dna[i: i + l] == key:

tmp = 1

while dna[i:i+l] == dna[ i+l : i+2*l ]:

tmp += 1

i += l

if tmp > tmpmax:

tmpmax = tmp

sequences[key] = tmpmax



#Read database file into a dictionary

with open(argv[1]) as peoplefile:

reader = DictReader(peoplefile)

#loop through STR counts, comparing it to each person's STR counts

for person in reader:

match = 0

for i in sequences:

if sequences[i] == int(person(i)):

match += 1

#if all the highest STR reps match the person, print that person's name

if match == len(sequences):

print(row['name'])

exit()


print("Does not match any person")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you try to run `reader = reader(peoplefile)` it's actually getting `reader` from your previous line of code `reader = reader(file)`.

In other words, your error line is trying to run something like this:

`reader = reader(file)(reader(peoplefile))`

Don't use the same name of a function as a variable. Using `csv_reader` as a variable instead of just `reader` solves the problem.

```
...
# read the file into memory
with open(argv[2]) as file:    
    csv_reader = reader(file)    
    for row in csv_reader:    
        dnalist = row
...
with open(argv[1]) as peoplefile:
    csv_reader = reader(peoplefile)
```

**EDIT**

I came up with an example to better explain what's going on:

Let's say you have a number that you want to convert to a string, set it to a new variable called str, and then print it.

```
x = 279
str = str(x)
print(str)
```

This code is syntactically correct but it may throw off later parts of your code, such as if you have another number and also want to convert it to string and print it.

```
x = 279
str = str(x)
print(str)

y = 441
str = str(y)
print(str)    # TypeError here
```

Using variable names with the same name as a function will overwrite that function and the next time you want to call the function you are actually calling the variable.

**Part 2**

And another way of looking at it, I figure the more examples the better:

Using only `import csv` makes it so you have to use `csv.reader()` to call the function

```
import csv

with open('example.txt') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for line in file:
        print(line)
    
with open('second_example_text.txt') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for line in file:
        print(line)
```

In this case, you can use `reader` as many times as you want because you aren't going to overwrite the function `csv.reader`

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks you solution worked. Why can I use csv_reader for everything but not reader? Shouldnt it work the same as having reader as a variable; it seems to me all I am doing is changing the name of the variable.

Comment: Idk if you got the notification but I updated the answer, check it out